# List splitting based on a condition

Tags: python, list, split

I have the following list and need to split it in as many lists as the values changes in it

1.0000000  46016.0000000   23.7303   8888.759 0.040   -0.5   -1.2 -1.99 -0.056  60   0 09:33:50     43076.39786    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   22.9979   8888.758 0.065   -0.5   -1.7 -2.00 -0.057  60   0 09:35:00     43076.39867    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   23.2420   8888.758 0.042    0.7   -2.0 -2.01 -0.057  60   0 09:36:05     43076.39942    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   22.9979   8888.757 0.049    2.6   -2.1 -2.03 -0.057  60   0 09:37:10     43076.40017    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   21.7772   8888.756 0.029    2.9   -1.9 -2.05 -0.058  60   0 09:38:16     43076.40093    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   21.0447   8930.649 0.061   -0.4   -1.0 -2.10 -0.062  60   0 09:53:36     43076.41156    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   21.0447   8930.648 0.056    0.0   -1.5 -2.11 -0.062  60   2 09:54:46     43076.41237    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   21.0447   8930.650 0.044    1.3   -2.3 -2.11 -0.063  60   0 09:55:51     43076.41312    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   20.8006   8930.649 0.046    0.4   -2.3 -2.13 -0.063  60   0 09:56:56     43076.41387    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   20.0682   8930.649 0.042    0.6   -1.8 -2.14 -0.063  60   0 09:58:02     43076.41464    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   20.8006   8916.477 0.043   -0.5   -1.3 -2.08 -0.069  60   0 10:24:02     43076.43266    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   20.8006   8916.478 0.047    0.0   -2.1 -2.08 -0.070  60   0 10:25:12     43076.43347    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   20.8006   8916.477 0.054    0.5   -2.4 -2.09 -0.070  60   0 10:26:17     43076.43422    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   20.8006   8916.477 0.053    2.1   -2.8 -2.09 -0.070  60   0 10:27:22     43076.43497    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   19.8240   8916.475 0.053    3.1   -2.9 -2.10 -0.070  60   0 10:28:28     43076.43574    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   21.7772   8888.743 0.046   -0.3    0.0 -1.98 -0.075  60   0 10:59:40     43076.45737    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   21.7772   8888.742 0.040    0.3   -0.8 -1.99 -0.075  60   0 11:00:50     43076.45818    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   21.7772   8888.741 0.049    0.6   -1.3 -2.01 -0.076  60   0 11:01:55     43076.45893    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   21.7772   8888.741 0.052    2.1   -1.6 -2.02 -0.076  60   0 11:03:00     43076.45968    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   20.5565   8888.740 0.044    2.7   -1.7 -2.04 -0.076  60   0 11:04:06     43076.46044    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   22.5096   8930.633 0.092   -1.8    1.0 -2.07 -0.077  60   0 11:20:05     43076.47152    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   22.0213   8930.635 0.089    0.2    1.1 -2.08 -0.077  60   3 11:21:15     43076.47233    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   22.2654   8930.632 0.100   -0.7   -0.4 -2.09 -0.077  60   0 11:22:20     43076.47308    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   22.5096   8930.633 0.073    0.6    0.9 -2.11 -0.077  60   0 11:23:25     43076.47384    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46019.0000000   21.7772   8930.630 0.074    2.3    0.2 -2.12 -0.078  60   0 11:24:31     43076.47460    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   24.7068   8916.463 0.050   -2.2   -0.2 -2.10 -0.078  60   0 11:49:28     43076.49190    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   24.7068   8916.464 0.052   -1.0   -1.3 -2.11 -0.078  60   0 11:50:38     43076.49271    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   24.4627   8916.463 0.041    1.1   -2.3 -2.13 -0.078  60   0 11:51:43     43076.49346    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   24.4627   8916.465 0.045    3.5   -3.0 -2.14 -0.078  60   0 11:52:48     43076.49421    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46015.0000000   23.7303   8916.465 0.042    7.3   -2.9 -2.15 -0.078  60   0 11:53:54     43076.49497    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   25.1951   8888.726 0.046   -3.1   -1.1 -2.03 -0.076  60   0 12:25:56     43076.51718    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   24.9510   8888.725 0.066   -1.9   -1.8 -2.04 -0.076  60   0 12:27:06     43076.51799    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   24.7068   8888.724 0.060   -1.8   -2.1 -2.04 -0.076  60   0 12:28:11     43076.51874    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   24.4627   8888.722 0.036   -0.5   -2.4 -2.06 -0.076  60   0 12:29:16     43076.51949    0.0000  2018/01/08
 1.0000000  46016.0000000   22.7537   8888.720 0.045   -0.2   -2.4 -2.08 -0.076  60   0 12:30:22     43076.52025    0.0000  2018/01/08

for this list I need to have the following lists:

```
list1 =  [ 1.0000000  46016.0000000   23.7303   8888.759 0.040   -0.5   -1.2 -1.99 -0.056  60   0 09:33:50     43076.39786    0.0000  2018/01/08
```

,1.0000000  46016.0000000   22.9979   8888.758 0.065   -0.5   -1.7 -2.00 -0.057  60   0 09:35:00     43076.39867    0.0000  2018/01/08
 ,1.0000000  46016.0000000   23.2420   8888.758 0.042    0.7   -2.0 -2.01 -0.057  60   0 09:36:05     43076.39942    0.0000  2018/01/08
 ,1.0000000  46016.0000000   22.9979   8888.757 0.049    2.6   -2.1 -2.03 -0.057  60   0 09:37:10     43076.40017    0.0000  2018/01/08
 ,1.0000000  46016.0000000   21.7772   8888.756 0.029    2.9   -1.9 -2.05 -0.058  60   0 09:38:16     43076.40093    0.0000  2018/01/08
]

and so on until the last one

```
list7 = [ 1.0000000  46016.0000000   25.1951   8888.726 0.046   -3.1   -1.1 -2.03 -0.076  60   0 12:25:56     43076.51718    0.0000  2018/01/08
```

,1.0000000  46016.0000000   24.9510   8888.725 0.066   -1.9   -1.8 -2.04 -0.076  60   0 12:27:06     43076.51799    0.0000  2018/01/08
 ,1.0000000  46016.0000000   24.7068   8888.724 0.060   -1.8   -2.1 -2.04 -0.076  60   0 12:28:11     43076.51874    0.0000  2018/01/08
 ,1.0000000  46016.0000000   24.4627   8888.722 0.036   -0.5   -2.4 -2.06 -0.076  60   0 12:29:16     43076.51949    0.0000  2018/01/08
 ,1.0000000  46016.0000000   22.7537   8888.720 0.045   -0.2   -2.4 -2.08 -0.076  60   0 12:30:22     43076.52025    0.0000  2018/01/08
]

The value to check that it changed is the tableau[11:27] for example '46016.0000000' so a new sublist is created
Your help is appreciated
I tried this code but it omits the last value:

```
    new_list = []

    if tableau[j][11:27].strip() == tableau[j+1][11:27].strip():
        new_list.append(tableau[j])
    else:
        new_list = []
```

Comment: What is the condition?

Comment: What data structure is `tableau`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there a reason you want variables `list1`...`list7`? Why not use a 2d list so you can iterate over it? I'm also not really clear what you're asking, but why not `[list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(your_list)]`

Comment: Daniel Mesejo : The condition is the change in the value

Comment: schwobaseggl: The tableau is a list of strings

Comment: ggorlen: Thanks it is a raw observation file with repetitive observations that I want to split based on a the point number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Thanks all for your help. I got a workaround that's working for me it is not pythonic but for now it do the job

## First I build a list of indexes where the change occur

```
if i1[11:27].strip()!=i2[11:27].strip():
    indexes.append(j-1)
```

## Then since in a normal file there are 6 changes then do a loop if the length of the list of indexes is equal to 6

```
chunks0 =chunks1 = chunks2 = chunks3 =chunks4 = chunks5= chunks6 = []

if len(indexes) == 6:
    print(indexes[0])
    chunks0 = tableau[0:indexes[0]+1]
    chunks1 = tableau[indexes[0] + 1: indexes[1]+1]
    chunks2 = tableau[indexes[1]+1: indexes[2]+1]
    chunks3 = tableau[indexes[2]+1: indexes[3]+1]
    chunks4 = tableau[indexes[3]+1: indexes[4]+1]
    chunks5 = tableau[indexes[4]+1: indexes[5]+1]
    chunks6 = tableau[indexes[5]+1: len(tableau)]
```

## Then just write the last five elements of every chunk in the output file

```
for ele in chunks0[-5:]:
    f_out.write(ele + '\n')

for ele in chunks1[-5:]:
    f_out.write(ele + '\n')

for ele in chunks2[-5:]:
    f_out.write(ele + '\n')

for ele in chunks3[-5:]:
    f_out.write(ele + '\n')

for ele in chunks4[-5:]:
    f_out.write(ele + '\n')

for ele in chunks5[-5:]:
    f_out.write(ele + '\n')

for ele in chunks6[-5:]:
    f_out.write(ele + '\n')
```

## That's it.

## Any help to make the code more pythonic and faster is welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

You could match your values using a pattern making use of a capturing group and a backreference.

```
(\d+\.\d+)(?: \1)*
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/grKqCu/1) | [Python demo](http://ideone.com/FCg4FD)

Then you could split the matches on a space.

```
import re

regex = r"(\d+\.\d+)(?: \1)*"
test_str = "46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46019.0000000 46019.0000000 46019.0000000 46019.0000000 46019.0000000 46015.0000000 46015.0000000 46015.0000000 46015.0000000 46015.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46019.0000000 46019.0000000 46019.0000000 46019.0000000 46019.0000000 46015.0000000 46015.0000000 46015.0000000 46015.0000000 46015.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000 46016.0000000"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
new_list = []

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    new_list.append(match.group().split(" "))

print(new_list)
```

Output

```
[['46016.0000000', '46016.0000000', '46016.0000000', '46016.0000000', '46016.0000000'], ['46019.0000000', '46019.0000000', '46019.0000000', '46019.0000000', '46019.0000000'], ['46015.0000000', '46015.0000000', '46015.0000000', '46015.0000000', '46015.0000000'], ['46016.0000000', '46016.0000000', '46016.0000000', '46016.0000000', '46016.0000000'], ['46019.0000000', '46019.0000000', '46019.0000000', '46019.0000000', '46019.0000000'], ['46015.0000000', '46015.0000000', '46015.0000000', '46015.0000000', '46015.0000000'], ['46016.0000000', '46016.0000000', '46016.0000000', '46016.0000000', '46016.0000000']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have a list of data and not a string

Answer (score 0):

you can just loop through the list and create list as new value appears

```py
lists = []
lsi = []
for i1,i2 in zip(ls, ls[1:]):
    lsi.append(i1)
    if i1!=i2:
        lists.append(lsi)
        lsi = []
print(lists)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but this omits the last element from the last created list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get funky with it, you can use list comprehension.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_of_lists = defaultdict(list)
[dict_of_lists[i].append(i) for i in big_list]
```

End up with a dict with keys that are the unique values, and the values of the dict is the list you want.

Comment: Thanks but I want to keep the entire values attached together for further processing